# Android Run Instrmentation Test Offline

Tags: android, gradle, code-coverage, jacoco, instrumentation

So I want to build my tests and app, and then run the instrumentation tests whenever I want, even when I do not have access to the code (and hence, cannot use `cAT` task)

I have tried using `assembleAndroidTest` to generate test apk. But when I install this apk (as well as the app apk) and run `am instrumentation` with correct arguments (`-e emma true`, and with correct runner class verified using `pm list instrumentation`), I get no `.ec` file under `/data/app/<package-name>`. There is no error however.

I am using JaCoCo and when I run the tests using `cAT`, the coverage report is generated so I guess my JaCoCo configs are Ok.